# Create a blue colored rectangular java bean

Tags: java, swing, javabeans

I am trying to write a code in Java to make a blue/green colored rectangular java bean.

Below is my code but it is not working :

File 1 :

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class JavaBean extends JFrame {

  private BlueRectangleBean blueRectangleBean;
  private JPanel container;

  public JavaBean() {
    setSize(400, 400);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("Java Bean Example");

    container = new JPanel();
    add(container);

    blueRectangleBean = new BlueRectangleBean();
    blueRectangleBean.setSize(100, 100);
    container.add(blueRectangleBean);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JavaBean jb = new JavaBean();
    jb.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

and

File 2

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class BlueRectangleBean extends JPanel {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  private int width;
  private int height;

  public BlueRectangleBean() {
    width = 50;
    height = 50;
  }

  public void setWidth(int width) {
    this.width = width;
  }

  public int getWidth() {
    return width;
  }

  public void setHeight(int height) {
    this.height = height;
  }

  public int getHeight() {
    return height;
  }
@Override
  protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
  }
}
```

There is not error, but I am not getting the required output. Any help with the same will be highly appreciated!

Comment: You're adding the BlueRectangleBean to a JPanel which by default uses a FlowLayout. FlowLayouts, and in fact *most* layouts don't respect a component's size but rather its preferred size. So one solution is to call `setPreferredSize(...)` on the BlueRectangleBean. Better would be to set the JPanel container's layout to BorderLayout, getting rid of `setSize(...)` and let the BlueRectangleBean fill up the JPanel. Either that or add the BlueRectangleBean directly to the JFrame's contentPane which also uses BorderLayout.

Comment: Also, to Wamika, you can also override the BlueRectangleBean's `public Dimension getPreferredSize()` method which is cleaner than calling `setPreferredSize(...)` on it. If I were to go this route, I'd get the `super.getPreferredSize()` in the same method and make sure that my width and height returned is the max of the super's and the image-drawing region.

Comment: Why does your bean extend `JPanel`?  Isn't a bean a plain Java getter/setter class?  You can use the `java.awt.Color` and `java.awt.Rectangle` classes to define a logical colored rectangle.

Comment: If you're using a `JPanel`, you don't need to override `paintComponent`, you could just use `setBackground` in the constructor